# How can I remove Install Shield Manager from my Computer?

Tags: windows-xp, thinkpad, sp3

How can I remove Install Shield Manager from my Computer? There is no entry that I can see in my "Add/remove Programs" utility.

Thinkpad T60.

XP SP3

Thanks.

EDIT July 17, 2010.
I was directed to "Soluto: http://www.soluto.com/" in another message on Superuser, posted by an employee of the company. It's free Boot Management Software. I like it. I have no connection with it other than as a user.

I was able to remove the install Shield Manager from my boot, which is all that really matters.

That software helped me. Thanks.

Comment: Oh man, Googling for this answer brings up nasty forums posts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an uninstaller go [here](http://consumerdocs.installshield.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=Q111006&sliceId=1) to get it

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that Install Shield Manager is something that is included in installer packages for programs you add and terminates when the target program is installed.  It does not live on your system independently and only functions during those specific installation processes.  I think it also has a counterpart for uninstalls.  So, the answer is it's not "on" your computer; it's "in" certain installation packages.